# Looking for a Toad for oracle feature in mysql

Tags: mysql, export

Does anyone know any free tools that will generate insert statements given a result set? I know TOAD for Oracle does it, i would need this for a mysql database.

For example, if I execute this query

```
select colA, colB from mytable where colC = 'numbers'; //returns many rows


|colA | colB  |
|1    | 'one' |
|2    | 'two' |
|3    | 'three|
```

I would be able to get

```
insert into mytable (colA, colB) values (1,'one');
insert into mytable (colA, colB) values (2,'two');
insert into mytable (colA, colB) values (3,'three');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [MySQL version of TOAD](http://www.quest.com/toad-for-mysql/). It probably has the same ability to export result sets.

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL you cna use the [LOAD DATA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html) statement

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with using SQL?

```
SELECT CONCAT(
    'INSERT INTO mytable (colA, colB) VALUES (',
    colA,
    ',\'',
    colB,
    '\';'
) AS line
FROM mytable
WHERE colC = 'numbers';
```

Or just skip the temp file and:

```
INSERT INTO dest_table (colA, colB)
SELECT colA, colB
FROM mytable
WHERE colC = 'numbers';
```

Answer (score 1):

http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/ is another tool that will allow this. It is Java based and works well for multiple databases.

Comment: definetly a good option. Many toad fan boys here, so this wasn't chosen, but personally find it very easy to use, and particularly  exporting insert statements is a 2 right click task. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try [sqldeveloper](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/what-is-sqldev-093866.html) . This [page](http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/oracle/06-may/o36sql.html) may help you do what exactly you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

[HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/) allows you to export whole grid or only selected rows

Answer (score 0):

IMO [TOra](http://torasql.com/) is closet tool to TOAD. This is a very good alternative to Toad and FREE.

http://torasql.com/